# Google app engine - how to disable the cache

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, google-cloud-platform

So some context:

I have a nodeJS api running on a google app engine. All my get requests are being cached by default by the app engine for 10 minutes.

I am using cloudflare for my API as this allows me to remove specific items from the cache when needed.

You can imagine this has caused a bit of an issue because my CF cache was correctly cleared but the app engine kept returning old data.

According to the docs, you can set a [default_expiration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-requests-are-handled#response_caching) in the app.yaml file but setting this to 0 or 0s has made no difference and google keeps caching my responses.

Seemingly, there is also no way you can get something uncached from google.

Now my obvious question here is: is there some way I can completely ignore this cache? Preferrably without having to set my entire API's response to private , 0s cache.

It quite irks me that google is forcing this cache on me provides very vague documentation on the whole matter.

Comment: Are you referring to the static file cache?  If so, it would be helpful to clarify that.

Comment: It's the default app engine response cache

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-handled#static_cache_expiration

It caches the response with the request URL as the full key.

Comment: I've been trying this out on my own to see if I could find anything to answer with, but I can't seem to get your same error. In my case it was just a matter of refreshing the browser without cache given that I simply used a basic nginx website to test this. Would you kindly provide us with a code snippet of your app.yaml configuration (what you can show, of course) so that we can try and get this error ourselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your `app.yaml` to define a cache period.

If you use [default_expiration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#default_expiration) this will set a global default cache period for all static file handlers for an application. If omitted, the production server sets the expiration to 10 minutes by default.

To set specific expiration times for individual handlers, specify the [expiration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_expiration) element within the handler element in your `app.yaml` file. You can change the duration of time web proxies and browsers should cache a static file served by this handler.

```yaml
default_expiration: "4d 5h"

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets
  expiration: "0d 0h"
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you are referring to the static cache (per your link). Try cache bursting techniques such as adding a query parameter to the url e.g.

```
https://<url>/?{{APP_VERSION_ID}}
```

where APP_VERSION_ID is the latest version of your deployed App. This way, each time you redeploy your App, the APP_VERSION_ID is changed and the latest version of your static files will always be loaded