# Nuxtjs on GAE is caching html and resulting in 404 on js files

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, nuxt.js, devops, browser-cache

I'm having a weird behavior with Nuxt in GAE.

I have 404 on JS files when updating production, it looks like HTML is being cached more than it should, always 304, so it's pointing to previous built js files that are not available anymore, I don't have this behavior in a common docker container, as soon as I create a new build, the html is served with 200 status code.

So basically if the user that previously have accessed doesn't clean the cache after the build, everything is broken.

These are my configurations (basically the same as the recommended on Nuxt docs), I've just removed the secure because it conflicts with cloudflare ssl:

app.yaml

```yaml
runtime: nodejs16

handlers:
  - url: /_nuxt
    static_dir: dist/_nuxt

  - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt))$
    static_files: static/\1
    upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt)$

  - url: /.*
    script: auto

automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 1
  min_instances: 1
```

nuxt.config.js

```js
{
  ssr: true,
  target: 'static'
}
```

build commands

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build && nuxt generate",
    "gcp-build": "nuxt build && nuxt generate",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
  }
}
```

I have tried to threat html files as static files on app.yaml but that lead to issues with router redirection (I redirect every non trailing slash url to with a trailing slash), sitemap was not available anymore, canonical urls were being built always leading to root path "/". So I gave up with this approach.

I don't believe is a Cloudflare reason either because the appspot.com url that Google provides have the same issue.

Comment: Can you check the application logs to make sure what happens on GAE using this command `gcloud app logs tail`?

Comment: Since you're using `target: 'static'`, only `nuxt generate` is needed. `nuxt build` is for `target: 'server'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google app engine - how to disable the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66457417/google-app-engine-how-to-disable-the-cache)